# When telomere length is measured, is the method performed on a collection of cells yielding an average?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, senescence, telomere, measurement

What are the methods used in measuring telomeres in human or animal subjects?

Can it be done on an individual cell?

Has the following concern been raised and addressed before:

What if there exists a natural variance in telomere length on a cell by cell basis and various methods exist (strenuous exercise etc) that exert selection pressure on telomere length, then if the measurement method in some way involves multiple cells you have the effect of the average length increasing while something else actually occurred. Resulting in all these studies concluding that telomere length increased.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! I suggest you to read policies related to homework questions (https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). This will greatly increase the chances that you receive appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A telomere can be measured using a flow-fish test. Basically fluorescent markers that bind DNA are introduced to the nucleus of a cell, and then those markers can be counted using a method call flow cytometry.

It can be done on one cell

I'm not sure I understand the last part of the question, but I can say that if the average telemore size increases in a particular sample size, then scientists will not conclude anything based on that data.

If there is a scientific conclusion on telomere size with relation to external selective pressures, there would be statistically significant data that properly accounts for the variations observed in different cells.